# Java how to call optString?

Tags: java, json

I recently have

> json-simple 1.1.jar

and

> json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar

I declared a json object and I wanted to use optString or something else that can retrieve null

I was currently using

> jsObject.get("key").toString

But it can't accept null.

Is there library that can call "optstring" in Java Netbeans or anyways that can retrieve null value

Comment: "_But it can't accept null._" could you post a [mcve] of this ?

Comment: I guess the obj.get("key") is null, when you apply toString() it throws NullPointerException, i have written a simple method for you, please check.

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you are not having much time to do, it is not difficult to make a custom method as follow, maybe put in a Util class:

```
public String getString(JSONObject obj, String key) {
    if (obj.get("key") == null) {
        return "";
    }else {
        return obj.get("key").toString();
    }
}
```

So, whenever you have to get string for that JSONObject, just call like:

```
String value = getString(obj, "key"); //if the method is declared in the same class
```

or

```
String value = Util.getString(obj, "key"); //if the method is declared in a Util class which can be reused everywhere
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it by changing to

> String value = (String) jsObj.get("Key");

I appreciate all of you for helping me